# How to add your own function in ActionMode class in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionmode

I want to implement an `ActionMode` which acts as a `selection mode`. I want to add a function `toggle()` in my `ActionMode` which toggles the selection of my list.

my `ActionMode` code:

```
class Selection(/* some parameters */): ActionMode.Callback {
    private val selectedPositions = ArrayList<Int>()

    fun toggle(position: Int) {
        if (selectedPositions.contains(position)) {
            selectedPositions.remove(position)
        } else {
            selectedPositions.add(position)
        }
    }

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean { /* some code */ }
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean { /* some code */ }
    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean = false
    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) { /* some code */ }
}
```

My problem is that I am not able to use the `toggle()` function from my calling activity/fragment. For example:

```
private var actionMode: ActionMode? = null
```

```
// initialising action mode
if (actionMode == null) {
    actionMode = activity!!.startActionMode(Selection(/* some parameters */))
}
```

```
// I am not able to do this
actionMode!!.toggle(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is on your Selection class, not the ActionMode class.  Call it on the instnce of the Selection class

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Save the selection you create in a variable. Then call toggle on that variable. If you don't understand that, you need to study cs enough to understand instances and methods